# Is there R function for specifying treatment group as indicator in linear regression?

Tags: r

I have original dataset collected for my  thesis survey experiment analyzing effects of various  crisis communication strategies on voter's public approval for politician who committed a political scandal. I have 4 treatment and 2 control groups, wherein T1, T2 and C1 refer to one type of scandal, and T3, T4 and C2 to another type. I need to run regression where

```
 lm(PoliticalApproval ~ Ideology + Education + Age + Sex + Plaus_1 + Seri_1 + FL_10_DO, data = c(Qualtricsdata))
```

FL_10_DO variable stands for treatment/control group (T1, T2, etc). How do i specify regression that would take C1 as a reference group, and have coefficients for T1 and T2 which represents different types of communication strategies? Is there a code in `R` to do that? Thank you

Comment: factor(FL_10_DO, levels = c(C1,T1,T2))

Comment: What do you mean with a reference group?

Comment: reference group as intercept

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by @daszlosek should work! You can also use relevel() command to make C1/C2 as your reference group. Here is the link to its R documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/relevel

If you wish to change the base level for all analyses on your data, you can do this:

```
# Make C1 as the reference group
Qualtricsdata$FL_10_DO_R <- relevels(Qualtricsdata$FL_10_DO, ref = "C1") 

#check the level to make sure we turn C1 into the reference group
levels(Qualtricsdata$FL_10_DO_R)
```

This should return something like this

```
> levels(Qualtricsdata$FL_10_DO_R)
[1] "C1" "XXX" "XXX"
```

You can also choose to use relevel inside your formula so it won't affect your original dataset.

```
lm(PoliticalApproval ~ Ideology + Education + Age + Sex + Plaus_1 + Seri_1 + relevel(FL_10_DO, ref = "C1"), data = c(Qualtricsdata))
```